# Want to solve the issue related with Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, react-native-testing-library

While writing test case for [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGkur.png)
this component i am getting continue error which i mentioned above.I had export my component like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpBMQ.png) and in my test file i had [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtOKU.png) this. how can i solve this issue?
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
    Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    Check the render method of `AppTextInput`.

      94 | describe('<AppTextInput />', () => {
      95 |   test('renders correctly with provided props', () => {
    > 96 |     const { getByTestId, getByPlaceholderText } = render(
```